# A Problem of Linear Algebra that can Stumps Anyone

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, general-linear-group

This problem encountered me during the study of balanced Boolean functions. I was in need of constructing those balanced Boolean functions for which $\mathcal{D}_bf\ne 1$. And finding the solution to this problem got converted to finding the solution of this problem.

---

Let $n\geq 4$ and $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2}$ with $\lvert\mathcal{A}\rvert=2^{n-1}$. Let matrix$(\mathcal{A})$ be the $2^{n-1}\times n$ sized matrix obtained by assuming elements of $\mathcal{A}$ as rows. Let $set(\mathcal{B})$ be set of all the rows of matrix $\mathcal{B}$. For $\textbf{b}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2}, \textbf{b}+\mathcal{A}:=\{\textbf{b}+\textbf{a} : \textbf{a}\in \mathcal{A}\}.$

$$\underline{\text{The problem is stated as follows:}}$$

Suppose $n\geq 4$ and $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2}$ with $\lvert\mathcal{A}\rvert=2^{n-1}$ and for every $\textbf{b}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2},$ we have $\mathcal{A}\cap (\textbf{b}+\mathcal{A})\neq \emptyset.$

$\mathit{Q1.}$ Find the number of such sets $\mathcal{A}$.

$\mathit{Q2.}$ For a given such set $\mathcal{A}$, find the number of $\mathcal{H}\in \mathcal{GL}(n, \mathbb{F}_{2})$ (where $\mathcal{GL}(n, \mathbb{F}_{2})$ is general linear group of $n*n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$) such that $set(matrix(\mathcal{A})*\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{A}.$

$$\underline{Example:}$$
For $n=4.$ There are $10080$ such sets $\mathcal{A}$.
$\text{If}\ \mathcal
{A} = \{[0 0 0 0],[1 0 0 0],[0 1 0 0],[1 1 0 0],[0 0 1 0],[1 0 1 0],[0 0 0 1],[0 1 0 1]\},$ equivalently,
$$matrix(\mathcal{A})=\begin{pmatrix}
 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 1& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 1& 0& 0\\
 1& 1& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 1& 0\\
 1& 0& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 1\\
 0& 1& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ We get $8$ matrices from $\mathcal{GL}(4, \mathbb{F}_{2}):$

$\mathcal{H}_{1}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 1& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{H}_{2}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{H}_{3}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 1\\
\end{pmatrix},$

$\mathcal{H}_{4}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 1\\
0& 0& 1& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$,

$\mathcal{H}_{5}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
 0& 1& 0& 0\\
 1& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 1\\
 1& 0& 1& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{H}_{6}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 0& 1& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{H}_{7}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 1\\
1& 0& 1& 0\\
\end{pmatrix},$

$\mathcal{H}_{8}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

These are the precise matrices for which $set(matrix(\mathcal{A})*\mathcal{H}_i )=\mathcal{A}.$ Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop, Sir this is not a $\textit{math contest question}$. This is a new problem encountered during the study of Boolean functions. I have tried it for $n=4,5$ but could not solve it in general.

Comment: Where does the problem come from then?

Comment: @Adam Rubinson I do not understand why for $n=4$ there are  $8$ and for $n=5$ there are $32$ such matrices. And how to find the number of such matrices for general $n$.

Comment: You ignored my question, which was, "where does the problem come from?" i.e. an exam? A Book? " I find it rude that you ignore my comment.

Comment: I’ve edited your question to add the motivational paragraph.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Sir, I did not ignore your comment, I already have discussed this problem encountered me during the study of balanced Boolean functions. I was in need of constructing those balanced Boolean functions for which $\mathcal{D}_{b}f≠1$. And then I found problem of construction of such types of functions is equivalent to finding the solution to the stated problem.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Thanks, sir.